# How to link python code to android application developed in java?

Tags: java, android, python

I have to develop an Android application which makes use of machine learning algorithms at the back end. Now, for developing the Android app, I use Java and for implementing the machine learning algorithms I use Python.

My question is how to link the Python code to an Android app written in Java. That is supposed my Python code generates an output, now how to send this data to an Android application?

Comment: is it a webapp, where you will write python code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to python from java android app. You can write python output in file, then in java code read that file.
Or if python output is in web, you will need some web service that provides json/xml output, and then in java code you should call that web service.

Comment: Ok. I will try this. Thanks for answering my doubt.